# ReferenceError: $ is not defined in firefox

Tags: jquery

This is my code:



    
    
        
        Jquery Ajax

```
    <script>
        $.ajax();
    </script>
    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>
</body>
```

I got from FireFox this error:

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$.ajax();

What can I do?

Comment: if jquery included it may be conflicting with php **?** or some other jquery plugin

Comment: Did you include jQuery?...

Comment: "*What can I do?*" — define `$`, by including jQuery before the attempt to use `$.ajax()`.

Comment: Yes I included it Scimonster.

Comment: Ehsan Sajjad: when i delete <?php ?> it works.
But now i need to write php code, how?

Comment: `var $ = {ajax: function(){}};` should fix this error :)

Comment: vp_arth: YES! thx. can u tell me why?!

Answer (score 1):

Did you import jquery to your HTML file?
try to add this--->

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>` to the header of your HTML file.

Comment: this is my full code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Jquery Ajax</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script>
         $.ajax();
        </script>
       
    </body>
    
    
</html>

Comment: first you have to download jQuery at following address [link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js),then put the js file in the same folder of your project,and change your change your <head> part to `<head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>Jquery Ajax</title><script src="jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </head>` and delete this ` <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/…; </script> `

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your answers and comments that help me.

I changed jQuery library version I used. Change my code to be: